# Add Custom Network(BNB) in Meta Mask Using web3

Tags: web3js, metamask, networkid

I am trying to add Binance Main and test net Network through web3 js. I don't want that user to setup it manually. Did you guys any idea about that how to handle it?

Comment: AFAIK this is still not possible with the current Metamask API.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use wallet_addEthereumChain method - https://docs.metamask.io/guide/rpc-api.html#other-rpc-methods

Example code:

```
window.ethereum.request({
method: 'wallet_addEthereumChain',
params: [{
chainId: '0x38',
chainName: 'Binance Smart Chain',
nativeCurrency: {
    name: 'Binance Coin',
    symbol: 'BNB',
    decimals: 18
},
rpcUrls: ['https://bsc-dataseed.binance.org/'],
blockExplorerUrls: ['https://bscscan.com']
}]
})
.catch((error) => {
console.log(error)
})
```

Comment: further to this https://chainlist.org, which is open source, has a large number of networks.